# Linear Thompson sampling - non linear relations dominate sampled rewards

Tags: reinforcement-learning, multiarmed-bandit, contextual-bandit

I'm implementing linear Thompson sampling for a project. I am simulating random features with rewards that are linear related to some features them and non linear to others.

For the non linear features, the variance of the distribution of the learned weights is huge. Because of that, the sampled values of these weights can be extremely small or big. That means that the predicted rewards based on the sampled weights will be dominated by these features, and in result are effectively random.

My question is: how can I apply LinearTS when I have features that don't linearly correlate with the rewards? Is this behaviour that I observed expected?

I would like to use the same model for different (hundreds) geographic aggregations of my data, so manual adjustments like removing features are not considered because a feature can be useful for one geography, but not for others.

It seems like I'm missing something about this method, so I welcome any guidance. Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I edited the question, thanks